# What is its name? or What is his/her name? (regarding a dog)

Tags: phrase-meaning

If you see a nice dog, how to ask its name? As I know this rule, we use "it" to all animals, except a favourite domestic animal. So, if it's not a favourite dog of your relative or neighbour, you can't ask:

> What is his/her name?

You must ask:

> What is its name?

Is that right?

Comment: It isn't that strict a rule! If the dog's gender is clearly visible, of course you can call it he or she. We use _it_ for an anonymous animal whose gender is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking to the owner of the dog, the animal is likely significant for that owner, so using *he*/*she* is a sign of politeness. Sure, you don't care much about the dog and to you the dog might be an *it*, but by using *he*/*she* you acknowledge the perspective of the person you're speaking to.

Neither *it* nor *he*/*she* would be an error here (unless you get the dog's gender wrong, of course).